# Creating a repeater dynamically inside an accordion pane

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

My goal is to nest a `Repeater` inside an ASP.Net AJAX `Accordion`'s `AccordionPane`.

So there is one Accordion which I am programmatically adding AccordionPanes to. The amount of panes I add depends on my particular dataset's count value, usually no more than 5. I've managed to do this successfully.

The thing I am having difficulty with is creating and adding a Repeater per each AccordionPane.

I've glanced over http://iridescence.no/post/Using-Templated-Controls-Programmatically.aspx but this is not exactly what I had in mind. Instead, I would rather declare a single Repeater as static HTML that I could then "clone" when I need. How can I achieve this? Obviously I would want each control's ID (within this declared Repeater) to be generated automatically each time i "clone" it.

The repeater looks like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptForum" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div runat="server" style="border:solid #d3d3d3 1px; border-bottom-width:0px;">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr><td align="left">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Font-Size="12px" />
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td align="left">
                    >>&nbsp;<asp:Label runat="server" Font-Size="12px" Text='<%# Eval("query") %>' />
                </td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I might add more fields to be databound as I progress.

Any ideas appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by adding the repeater to the `Content` template:

```
<cc1:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
    <Header>
        Foo
    </Header>    
    <Content>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" ...>
            ...
        </asp:Repeater>
    </Content>
</cc1:AccordionPane>
```

Comment: Yes, it works when I add a Repeater like that. But what if I want to duplicate a Repeater (the one I pasted above) and dynamically add it to a new AccordionPane, all from the code behind..

Answer (score 0):

You can do a hierarchical data bind with the accordion, as illustrated here: http://aspalliance.com/1674_complex_data_binding_with_the_accordion_control

Comment: Thanks! Gonna check this out now to see if it's what I need.